# How to perform stress test against sharepoint site using threads

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, performance, testing, load-testing

I want to analyze the performance (hence its weak points) of a sharepoint site doing stress test activity. What is needed to be done is call some methods exposed via web service that do the following things inside the sharepoint site:

```
-create a new group 
-add a content to the group 
-add an attachment to the content 
-delete the content 
-delete the previously created group
```

What is required is a simulation of a situation where there are 4500 users trying to do these operations concurrently (at the same time or more realistically within a short timespan, for example within 5 seconds).

We want to register the execution time of each operation (web method, for example of the "create new group"), too. I thought I could simulate these operations via a console applications using threads and stopwatchs. Is there anyone who has encountered a similar problem and can give me any existing solutions or hints to do it "the right way"? For 
example how can I obtain that all threads start at the same instant? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the load testing tools built into visual studio.  You could create a webserverive or webpart on a page that does each of your actions and then configure them to be called using the load testing tools.  They work pretty well.